# Insert is not visible sometimes in same transaction

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I am inserting data in table using below code

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query,mapSqlParameterSource);
org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(query1,SqlParameterSource,mapper);
```

**Query**

```
insert into table1(col1,col2) 
select col1,col2 from table2
```

But sometimes this insertion is not visible in the next select statement in the same transaction.
My observation is when lot of records are inserted in first query then data is not visible in next select statement.

I am not able to understand the root cause there is no failure/exception in the logs and the records are getting inserted properly only the immediate selection of those records within the same transaction sometimes doesn't give any result

Any insight will be really helpful.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Are you using RAC?  In older versions of Oracle (or if you happen to override the default RAC settings in later versions), it is possible that the `select` would run on a different node than the `insert` where the data is not yet visible.

Comment: HI @JustinCave Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production is the version

Comment: Are you using RAC?

Comment: Checked with DBA .We are not using RAC

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending both queries on the same statement, both are runned at the same time on the DBMS so if the select statement is faster than the insert one is not going to bring back all the data, try waiting for the insertion to complete before sending the select query.